# CSS3 animation with keyframes and transform

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I would like to make a similar move with CSS animations:

http://truthlabs.com/

I created a file where I'm working with keyframes , but does not work well.

I wish that the circles were able to make a full turn on the axis , starting from a fixed point in the center.

Thanks.

HTML FILE:

```
    <ul>
        <li style="animation: move1 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move2 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move3 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move4 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move5 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move6 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move7 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move8 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move9 2s infinite;"></li>
        <li style="animation: move10 2s infinite;"></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

CSS FILE:

```
        body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    ul{
        display: block;
        width: 1920px;
        height: 1080px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }

    @keyframes move1 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-46%, -50%);
        width:400px; height:400px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-54%, -50%);
        width:400px; height:400px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-46%, -50%);
        width:400px; height:400px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move2 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -46%);
        width:405px; height:405px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -54%);
        width:405px; height:405px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -46%);
        width:405px; height:405px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move3 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-47%, -50%);
        width:410px; height:410px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-55%, -50%);
        width:410px; height:410px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-47%, -50%);
        width:410px; height:410px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move4 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -48%);
        width:415px; height:415px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -56%);
        width:415px; height:415px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -48%);
        width:415px; height:415px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move5 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-49%, -50%);
        width:420px; height:420px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-57%, -50%);
        width:420px; height:420px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-49%, -50%);
        width:420px; height:420px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move6 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width:425px; height:425px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -58%);
        width:425px; height:425px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width:425px; height:425px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move7 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        width:430px; height:430px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-59%, -50%);
        width:430px; height:430px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
        width:430px; height:430px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move8 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -52%);
        width:435px; height:435px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
        width:435px; height:435px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -52%);
        width:435px; height:435px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move9 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-53%, -50%);
        width:440px; height:440px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-61%, -50%);
        width:440px; height:440px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-53%, -50%);
        width:440px; height:440px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move10 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -54%);
        width:445px; height:445px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -62%);
        width:445px; height:445px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -54%);
        width:445px; height:445px; 
      }
    }
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ntqtszay7BOg4pz8zCv4?p=preview

Comment: Hi, please note that you really should include all relevant code in your question rather than only linking to a demo. (And no...`@` is not relevant code.) If your code is too lengthy to include, please at least provide enough code for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is done using javascript

Comment: I know it was trying to recreate it with CSS . Tips about the javascript solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are going for? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/kn7qjg6c/5/

```
 @keyframes move1 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-46%, -50%);
        width:400px; height:400px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-54%, -50%);
        width:400px; height:400px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-46%, -50%);
        width:400px; height:400px; 
      }
    }

    @keyframes move2 {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -46%);
        width:1000px; height:1000px; 
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -54%);
        width:405px; height:405px; 
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -46%);
        width:405px; height:405px; 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo , but actually what I want to create is not about the entry or exit of the elements , but it is the static phase where the circles are all in the center and floating.

Comment: @SimonePignatelli something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/kn7qjg6c/6/